# Laravel 5.6 - Only save value if it has changed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.6 project and am trying to update a post from a form like this

```
<input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="{{$user->email}}" required>
```

In my PostsController I have this...

```
    if($request->input('email')) {
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
    }
```

I wanted it to only update the email if a new one has been input in the form, but because I am pre-populating the form fields it always passes the IF.

Is there a more Laravel way to do this? I have looked at isDirty() but I am not sure it is the correct thing to use.

Comment: Is there a problem with `if($request->input('email') && $user->email != $request->input('email'))` ?

Comment: you may set this value to be unique in your database and validate it

Comment: Yes, you can use isDIrty() function go for it.

Comment: what are you trying to do by saving only if new value? you're already updating the model and the email value won't change since it's the same value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The save() method  will check if something in the model has changed. If there is no change it won't run a db query.  So you don't need to explicitly write a code for that.
Still if you want to use isDirty method you can write as follows

```
if($test->isDirty()){
    // changes have been made
}
```

Or if you want to check a certain attribute:

```
if($test->isDirty('email')){
   // email has changed
}
```